# Variable save() in Laravel returns less attributes than findOrFail

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a controller action where it takes all of the inputs through requests and puts in the values into the class Shipment, right before committing the action `$shipment = Shipment::save();`

However if I return dd($shipment) I get the following attributes (and nothing more):

```
"pro_number" => "231776"
    "shipment_origin" => "1"
    "date" => "2018-04-18 00:00:00"
    "due_date" => "2018-05-18 00:00:00"
    "tractor_id" => null
    "trailer_id" => null
    "driver_id" => null
    "notes" => null
    "shipper_no" => null
    "ship_to" => "200"
    "ship_from" => "200"
    "bill_to" => "200"
    "bill_type" => "1"
    "load_date" => null
    "shipment_status" => 1
    "shipment_billing_status" => 1
    "created_by" => 1
    "cn_billtoName" => null
    "cn_billtoAddress1" => null
    "cn_billtoAddress2" => null
    "cn_billtoCity" => null
    "cn_billtoState" => null
    "cn_billtoZip" => null
    "cn_billtoEmail" => null
    "cn_billtoPhone" => null
    "cn_shiptoName" => null
    "cn_shiptoAddress1" => null
    "cn_shiptoAddress2" => null
    "cn_shiptoCity" => null
    "cn_shiptoState" => null
    "cn_shiptoZip" => null
    "cn_shiptoEmail" => null
    "cn_shiptoPhone" => null
    "cn_shipfromName" => null
    "cn_shipfromAddress1" => null
    "cn_shipfromAddress2" => null
    "cn_shipfromCity" => null
    "cn_shipfromState" => null
    "cn_shipfromZip" => null
    "cn_shipfromEmail" => null
    "cn_shipfromPhone" => null
    "fuelChargeDesc" => null
    "fuelChargeAmt" => "0.00"
    "fuelChargeTotal" => "0.00"
    "permitChargeDesc" => null
    "permitChargeAmt" => "0.00"
    "permitChargeTotal" => "0.00"
    "otherChargeDesc" => null
    "otherChargeAmt" => "0.00"
    "otherChargeTotal" => "0.00"
    "noCharge" => null
    "noSettle" => null
    "Total" => "10.00"
    "Balance" => "10.00"
    "freightBillSubtotal" => "10.00"
    "updated_at" => "2018-04-18 18:20:11"
    "created_at" => "2018-04-18 18:20:11"
    "id" => 9739
```

Of course, all of this information is technically correct. BUT, it is missing a few fields, one being the UUID field I have setup to be created upon record insert in MySQL.

However, if I change the following to the bottom of my controller action:

```
$shipmentDD = Shipment::findOrFail($shipment);
return dd($shipmentDD);
```

I get three $shipment back, rather than the only one that yielded above. However, one of the three was the correct Shipment and did in fact have the UUID field in the attributes.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this? I have a feeling it's because I'm not an expert with Laravel, still learning and all.

Update to include screenshot of shipment and attributes:
[image]

My entire controller action:

```
$this->validate(request(), [

            'pro_number' => 'required',
            'shipment_origin' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required',
            'due_date' => 'required'
            /*'piecesNumber' => 'required' (had to remove for now, but must review)*/

            ]);

            $user_id = Auth::id();

            $input = $request->all();

            //Save Initial Shipment Data
            $shipment = new Shipment();
            $shipment->pro_number = request('pro_number');
            $shipment->shipment_origin = request('shipment_origin');
            $shipment->date = request('date');
            $shipment->due_date = request('due_date');
            $shipment->tractor_id = request('tractor_id');
            $shipment->trailer_id = request('trailer_id');
            $shipment->driver_id = request('driver_id');
            $shipment->notes = request('notes');
            $shipment->shipper_no = request('shipper_no');
            $shipment->ship_to = request('ship_to');
            $shipment->ship_from = request('ship_from');
            $shipment->bill_to = request('bill_to');
            $shipment->bill_type = request('bill_type');
            $shipment->load_date = request('load_date');
            $shipment->shipment_status = 1;
            $shipment->shipment_billing_status = (isset($request->shipment_billing_status) && !empty($request->shipment_billing_status)) ? $request->shipment_billing_status : 1;
            $shipment->created_by = $user_id;
            $shipment->cn_billtoName = request('cn_billtoName');
            $shipment->cn_billtoAddress1 = request('cn_billtoAddress1');
            $shipment->cn_billtoAddress2 = request('cn_billtoAddress2');
            $shipment->cn_billtoCity = request('cn_billtoCity');
            $shipment->cn_billtoState = request('cn_billtoState');
            $shipment->cn_billtoZip = request('cn_billtoZip');
            $shipment->cn_billtoEmail = request('cn_billtoEmail');
            $shipment->cn_billtoPhone = request('cn_billtoPhone');
            $shipment->cn_shiptoName = request('cn_shiptoName');
            $shipment->cn_shiptoAddress1 = request('cn_shiptoAddress1');
            $shipment->cn_shiptoAddress2 = request('cn_shiptoAddress2');
            $shipment->cn_shiptoCity = request('cn_shiptoCity');
            $shipment->cn_shiptoState = request('cn_shiptoState');
            $shipment->cn_shiptoZip = request('cn_shiptoZip');
            $shipment->cn_shiptoEmail = request('cn_shiptoEmail');
            $shipment->cn_shiptoPhone = request('cn_shiptoPhone');
            $shipment->cn_shipfromName = request('cn_shipfromName');
            $shipment->cn_shipfromAddress1 = request('cn_shipfromAddress1');
            $shipment->cn_shipfromAddress2 = request('cn_shipfromAddress2');
            $shipment->cn_shipfromCity = request('cn_shipfromCity');
            $shipment->cn_shipfromState = request('cn_shipfromState');
            $shipment->cn_shipfromZip = request('cn_shipfromZip');
            $shipment->cn_shipfromEmail = request('cn_shipfromEmail');
            $shipment->cn_shipfromPhone = request('cn_shipfromPhone');
            $shipment->fuelChargeDesc = request('fuelChargeDesc');
            $shipment->fuelChargeAmt = request('fuelChargeAmt');
            $shipment->fuelChargeTotal = request('fuelChargeTotal');
            $shipment->permitChargeDesc = request('permitChargeDesc');
            $shipment->permitChargeAmt = request('permitChargeAmt');
            $shipment->permitChargeTotal = request('permitChargeTotal');
            $shipment->otherChargeDesc = request('otherChargeDesc');
            $shipment->otherChargeAmt = request('otherChargeAmt');
            $shipment->otherChargeTotal = request('otherChargeTotal');
            $shipment->noCharge = request('noCharge');
            $shipment->noSettle = request('noSettle');
            $shipment->Total = request('Total');
            if ((request('shipment_billing_status') == 2) || (request('shipment_billing_status') == 3)){
               $balance = 0.00;
            }else{
               $balance = request('Total');
            }
            $shipment->Balance = $balance;
            $shipment->freightBillSubtotal = request('freightBillSubtotal');

            $shipment->save();

            //Save Shipment Details
            $shipmentID = $shipment->id;

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->shipment_details['piecesNumber']); $i++) {
                //the first line used to be 'shipment_id' => $shipment->pro_number,
                Shipment_Detail::create([
                    'shipmentID' => $shipmentID, 
                    'pieces_number' => $request->shipment_details['piecesNumber'][$i],
                    'pieces_type' => $request->shipment_details['piecesType'][$i],
                    'rate_type' => $request->shipment_details['rateType'][$i],
                    'charge' => $request->shipment_details['charge'][$i],
                    'weight' => $request->shipment_details['weight'][$i],
                    'hazmat' => $request->shipment_details['hazmat'][$i],
                    'description' => $request->shipment_details['description'][$i] ]);
            }

            $carrier = Customer::where('carrier','=',1)->get();
            foreach($carrier as $car){
                            $carrierUsers = $car->users;
                            if ($carrierUsers->count() > 0){
                                foreach($carrierUsers as $carrierUser){
                                    $carrierUser->notify(new FreightBillNew($shipment));
                                }
                    }
                    }  

            Session::flash('success_message','Freight Bill Successfully Created'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE

            //Return to Register//
            $shipment_details = $shipment->shipment_details;
            $shipmentAudits = $shipment->audits;
            $attachmentTypes = file_type::all();
            $attachmentVisibilities = visibility::all();
            $customerAccount = Auth::user()->customers;
            $freightBillSubtotal = $shipment_details->sum('charge');

return redirect('/shipments/show/'.$shipment->UUID)->with('create_code', 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the UUID being set in the DB? If so, you have to get a fresh copy of the model from the DB:

```php
$shipment = Shipment::create($attributes)->fresh();
```

Comment: Yes, the UUID is being set in MySQL after I had a bad run in with something from Github. However, do I have to define the $attributes before hand or this is just handled through Laravel and then returned as the $attributes I listed out?

Comment: @Matthew - where have you listed them out?

Comment: I had listed them out in the first code block, but I also included a screenshot (below my original question) of the shipment in relation to the current "attributes returned". Also, I have included my entire controller command, would I put your suggested code right before the return redirect?

Comment: @Matthew You will need to call `fresh()` *before* calling the redirect since the UUID is being set in the database (as mentioned by Joseph). Calling `fresh()` re-fetches a new model instance from the database. The UUID will then become available. Keep in mind though this does not *sync* the models existing attributes. It will return a new model instance which you will have to set to a new variable.

Comment: There's also a `refresh` method, which updates the existing model.